# Loop through DV range and send to printer

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have some code that loops through a Data validation list and prints the page as a PDF file, I cant figure out how to tweak it to just send the page to the printer instead of printing as a PDF.

```
Sub Button11_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cell As Range
Dim rgDV As Range
Dim DV_Cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
Dim LA As Boolean
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer


Set DV_Cell = Range("B1")

Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
    A = Application.InputBox("Enter Page From")
    B = Application.InputBox("Enter Page To")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
        DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value

        strFile = Cells.Range("B1") & " Period " & Cells.Range("J1")
        strFile = Cells(5, 17).Value & "\" & strFile & ".PDF"
         ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
         Type:=xlTypePDF, _
         Filename:=strFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
         OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
         From:=A, _
         To:=B
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838253.aspx

Comment: Thank you, have  tested the below and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Button11_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cell As Range
Dim rgDV As Range
Dim DV_Cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
Dim LA As Boolean
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer


Set DV_Cell = Range("B1")

Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
     A = Application.InputBox("Enter Page From")
     B = Application.InputBox("Enter Page To")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

        For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
            DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value
                ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=A, To:=B

        Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```